# Algorithm to find neighbours of point by distance with no repeats

Tags: algorithm, math, distance, nearest-neighbor

I have an array of points formatted like this: `[point(0,0), point(0,0), point(0,0)]`, where `0,0` is replaced with the location of the point. I would like to interconnect them all by distance, for example:
[connecting.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWs57.png).
This would be done by looping over each point (loop 1), and then nesting another loop of all the points except for the current one (loop 2), then calculating the distance between the value from loop 1 and loop 2, then if it is less than the threshold, that is a neighbour and return in in an array.

The problem happens when I get doubled up values, for example it has found that point 1 is a neighbour of point 2, but also that point 2 is a neighbour of point 1, so when I connect them, they will be doubled up. I know of the nearest neighbour algorithm, but that only selects the closest, and won't it also just do the duplicate thing again??

Comment: Have you considered, for example, associating an array with each point to store all its connections? Then, when creating a new connection, you would check whether it already exists in the array.

Comment: or not even associating it with each point: just have a "scoped to your edge building" dictionary that, when you create a link between p1 and p2, you set both the keys `p1-p2` and `p2-p1` to `True`, so that when you hit p2 and your code wants to form an edge to p1, it can just check that dict and see that `p2-p1` already exists in O(1)

Comment: Use two nested loops. The outer loop runs from `i=0` to `i=N-2`. The inner loop runs from `j=i+1` to `j=N-1`. Given that N is the number of elements in the array, and 0-based indexing is being used.

Comment: "I know of the nearest neighbour algorithm, but that only selects the closest, and won't it also just" seems like an incomplete thought. Were you planning on finishing that or adding code? Showing your loops in their current form would make it easier to show how to modify them to meet your needs.